# Create a modeless dialog box that starts inactivated (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to make a modeless dialog box that shows itself without being activated.
I tried

```
m_ReminderDialog = new CReminderDialog();
m_ReminderDialog->Create(CReminderDialog::IDD, GetDesktopWindow());
```

with the dialog template

```
IDD_REMINDER DIALOGEX 0, 0, 318, 269
STYLE DS_SETFONT | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_THICKFRAME 
EXSTYLE WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
...
```

But it still comes up activated.
I tried making a window directly, not in MFC and using  `CreateWindowEx`, with

```
WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_APPWINDOW
```

That worked. The window comes up inactive, but it can be activated by clicking on the taskbar button.
I read that the call to `Create` activates the window. Is that true, and if so is there a way to create the modeless dialog box that doesn't override `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `WS_VISIBLE` style from your template, then add (after `Create()`):

```
m_ReminderDialog->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
```

Reference info: [`ShowWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the code I posted *does* create the dialog box, without giving it the input focus.
I just thought it had the input focus, for two reasons -

- The title bar on the dialog isn't grayed out
- When I tried `CreateWindowEx` in a separate program, using that same `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` flag, it could only be activated by clicking on the taskbar button.  So `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` acts differently when used in the dialog template than it does when calling `CreateWindowEx`.

I tried the code as written, with a call to `Sleep` before creating the dialog window, so I had time to set focus to a text document.  Then I waited until the dialog box was created.

After the dialog box was created, I was able to keep typing into the text document, so the dialog box did not have input focus. I was also able to put the dialog box on top of other windows with a couple calls to `SetWindowPos`, still without giving it the input focus.

However, `WS_EX_NOACTIVATE` does *not* work when  `DS_SETFOREGROUND` is also used in the dialog template. Not surprisingly.